# Trouble adding django-recaptcha to a registration form

Tags: python, django, forms, recaptcha

I'm having trouble adding django-recaptcha to a registration form.  The form is an extension of django-registration's forms.  Here's how I've got it plugged in (only showing relevant code):

*urls.py:*

```
from registration_custom.forms import RegistrationFormUniqueEmail

url(r'^accounts/register/$', 'registration_custom.views.register',
{'form_class':RegistrationFormUniqueEmail,
    'backend':'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend' }, name='registration_register',),
```

*registration_custom.forms.py:*

```
from captcha.fields import ReCaptchaField 

class RegistrationFormUniqueEmail(RegistrationForm):
    """
    Subclass of ``RegistrationForm`` which enforces uniqueness of
    email addresses.

    """
    # added recaptcha
    captcha = ReCaptchaField()

    def clean_email(self):
        """
        Validate that the supplied email address is unique for the
        site.

        """
        if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=self.cleaned_data['email']):
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address."))
        return self.cleaned_data['email']
```

I've checked to see if maybe my recaptcha keys were correctly and they are, and the keys are set up for the domain I'm using to test.

Can you spot something I missed?  Thanks.

Comment: did you add recaptcha to installed apps ?

Comment: what's the exact problem?

Comment: 'captcha' has been added to INSTALLED_APPS; the problem is that the recaptcha doesn't appear on the form.